# Chat keeps glitching

Tags: bug, chat

**EDIT**

Two months later this is still happening, and more frequently now. It is starting to become an issue...

As far as I can see, there is no pattern to when this occurs. I would very much appreciate any help.

(I am going to attempt to film it so it is easier to see what is happening)

---

Okay so this keeps happening. Every so often the last message flies up the page very suddenly leaving a massive space behind:

[image]

And then when I try and type anything it timeouts. It only works and resets correctly when I reload.

Comment: Can confirm, it always happens to me on Unix systems such as Ubuntu and Mac OS X.

Comment: @AndrewLi ah good thanks. Was worried it was just my computer because its been playing up lately, but seems like this is a bug then

Comment: It started happening a long time ago but I never got around to reporting and nobody I talked to experienced it. Good to see it wasn't just me, too.

Comment: What browser / OS are you using?

Comment: @Oded google chrome

Comment: That' browser. What Operating System (Windows/Mac/Linux/Something else)? What versions too?

Comment: @Oded windows 10

Comment: Is it all chat rooms or just one (and if just one, which one?). How long has this been happening?

Comment: @Oded I'm only active in one chat room - The sphinx's lair. I can try other chats to see if it happens though. It's been happening for the last week.

Comment: Are you accessing chat over http or https? Have you seen any errors in the developer tools (if you don't know what I am talking about, that's fine)?

Comment: @Oded https and I don't know about the developer tools

Comment: What's [the green icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A88bY.png)?

Comment: @TimStone grammarly. Not sure if it's anything to do with that

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it may have to do something with this if it is a Userscript or extension. Can't say for sure. But disable that thing and try again

Comment: @Oded I think the `http` will be redirected to `https`

Comment: @redhand perhaps but it was happening before I added it as an extension